# Using typeid to get name of derived class

Tags: c++

I'm creating a resource manager that takes in classes derived from the class `Resource`. My problem is that typeid(..).name() returns the wrong name of the class.

I want to add resources like Texture to a map like this:

```
typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, Resource*> ResourceMap;
```

And I want the name of the 'class + counter' to be the string/name of the Resource. Unfortunately everything just ends up being called `P8Resource` because these classes derive from 'Resource'. An untimely predicament indeed, but typeid must know somehow that `texture` is a Texture, not Resource.

```
class Resource {}; // abstract

class Texture : public Resource {};

Resource *texture = new Texture();
Texture *texture2 = new Texture();

typeid(texture).name(); // yields 'Resource'
typeid(texture2).name(); // yields 'Texture'
```

How can I make the first `typeid` statement yield 'Texture' without using type conversions?

Comment: Why not make a virtual function called `name` that will return a string with the information from the class that you want?

Comment: Huh?? You can't since `Resource`  never was instantiated??

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> My problem is that typeid(..).name() returns the wrong name of the
>   class.

`typeid(...).name()` is only useful for debugging or logging purposes. As http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name says:

> No guarantees are given, in particular, the returned string can be
>   identical for several types and change between invocations of the same
>   program.

As for your problem,

> How can I make the first typeid statement yield 'Texture' without
>   using type conversions?

The safest, easiest and most correct way to do this would be to add a virtual name function of your own to `Resource`:

```
virtual std::string name() const = 0;
```

Then override it in every subclass to return the name of the class.

Comment: `Resource` most likely also needs a virtual destructor.

Comment: I have deliberated on something like that; it's probably the most tedious but effective solution.

Comment: @Poriferous: That's just the way it is. C++ has no Java-like reflection. On the plus side, this makes code more robust and predictable.

Comment: @Brian: In the OP's real code, that is. Of course, he should have added it to his code snippet posted here.

Comment: Rest assurred I do have a virtual destructor. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 44):

`typeid` of a pointer will always be the declared type, because that's the real type of the pointer itself.  To know the real type of the object the pointer points to, you need to dereference the pointer to get the actual type: http://ideone.com/FYmp79

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

struct Resource {
    virtual ~Resource() = default;
};

struct Texture : Resource {};

int main() {
    Resource *resource = new Resource;
    Resource *texture = new Texture;

    cout << typeid(*resource).name() << endl; // yields 'Resource'
    cout << typeid(*texture).name() << endl; // yields 'Texture'
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: as other people said, you need to make the class polymorphic to get the runtime type information.

Comment: According to Christian Hackl, seems to be an attitude of typeid to deliver the non-polymorphic pointer type

Answer (score 8):

Firstly, `typeid` can provide dynamic run-time type identification only for values of *polymorphic* class types. Your classes are not polymorphic. You need at least one virtual method in the base class in order to "activate" the dynamic behavior of `typeid`.

Secondly, in order to use `typeid` for determining the dynamic type of polymorphic object, you have to apply it *to the object itself*, not to a pointer to the object (as in your code).

Thirdly, the value returned by `name()` does not mean much and cannot be used for any practical purposes. Formally, `name()` can simply return an empty string every time. You have to use (and compare) the `type_info` objects themselves for run-time type identification.

Answer (score 3):

The `typeid` operator can only return the *dynamic type* of an expression, if that expression is a glvalue to an object of a *polymorphic* class.

A class is *polymorphic* if it defines at least one virtual member function, directly or in one of its bases.

Since your `Resource` class and the derived classes don't satisfy this requirement, the `typeid` operator can only access the *static type*.

To solve that, and issues that you will run into as soon as you try to `delete` a pointer to such a resource, make the destructor virtual.

Comment: I don't know who downvoted your answer, but my question too was downvoted. I've neutralised your downvote along with the other answer since I know both your answers were helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Qt library, you could use the metaobject to distinguish the resource instances.

```
class Resource : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

}; // abstract

class Texture : public Resource {
    Q_OBJECT
};

Resource *texture = new Texture();
Resource *resource = new Resource();

texture ->metaObject()->className(); // yields 'Texture'
resource ->metaObject()->className(); // yields 'Resource'
```