# Return alias identificator instead of type in typeid(SOME_TYPE).name()

Tags: c++, c++11

In the following example

```
template <typename T>
void foo() {
    const char* name = typeid(T).name();
    std::cout << name;
}
```

the variable 'name' will be initialized by type 'T' name. It is very convinient if we need to print this template type name. But, if we have the alias:

```
using shortTypeName = std::smth::smth_else::smth_more;
```

in the result of the call

```
foo<shortTypeName>();
```

will be printed 'std::smth::smth_else::smth_more'. And I need to print exactly the alias name, but not the type it is defined. Can somebody give an advice, how I can do this?

Comment: You can't, `name()` is implementation defined.

Comment: You should only use typeid for debugging purposes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32016809/using-typeid-to-get-name-of-derived-class

Comment: I don't think you can avoid RTTI with the current C++ standard version. I.e. there is no compile time reflection in C++ yet.

Comment: Also, afaik an alias is just a new name for a type so it would share the same typeid, i dont think theres any way for typeid to know which one it should give you

Comment: The only thing that can help you here is a stringification macro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... alias identificator ...

There's no such thing, at least not after compilation. It's just syntactic sugar and doesn't exist in any sense in the final executable.

The *only* way to grab the local name of a type (as opposed to the implementation-defined and probably-mangled typeid name) is with a stringize/stringify macro.

---

For future reference, this should eventually be possible when the [Reflection TS](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/reflect) lands - but I don't yet know whether to expect that to look like `reflexpr(T).get_name()`, or `std::meta::name_of(^T)`, or something else again.

Answer (score 1):

> Can somebody give an advice, how I can do this?

The language does not support a mechanism to do this.

What you have is simply a type alias.

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias:

> A type alias declaration introduces a name which can be used as a synonym for the type denoted by type-id. It does not introduce a new type and it cannot change the meaning of an existing type name.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Because a type alias is transparent: It is just a synonym for a new type, not a new type. As an implementation detail it doesn't even get mangled in the type system because it's not a type.

> §7.1.3 The typedef specifier [dcl.typedef]
>
> 1. [...] A name declared with the typedef specifier becomes a typedef-name . Within the scope of its declaration, a typedef-name is
>      syntactically equivalent to a keyword and names the type associated
>      with the identifier in the way described in Clause 8. A typedef-name
>      is thus a synonym for another type. **A typedef-name does not
>      introduce a new type** the way a class declaration (9.1) or enum
>      declaration does.
> 2. A typedef-name can also be introduced by an alias-declaration . The identifier following the using keyword becomes a typedef-name and the
>      optional attribute-specifier-seq following the identifier appertains
>      to that typedef-name . It has the same semantics as if it were
>      introduced by the typedef specifier. In particular, **it does not
>      define a new type** and it shall not appear in the type-id .

`typeid(T).name();` is pretty much useless anyway. Until we have proper introspection in C++ you have to resort to hacks to get what you want (macros, intrusive techniques or external code generator tools).